# Ordenar de derecha a izquierda en Canvas

Tags: javascript

Tengo este for el cual me coloca unas imagenes de izquierda a derecha.

con este arreglo.

```
arrText = [435, 820, 795, 915];
var scala = 7.5;


    if (check.checked & Bminus == '1') {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrText.length; i++) {
    parseFloat(arrText[i]);
    distancia = (arrText[i] + (aux)) / scala;
    distancia = parseInt(distancia);
    distanciaPosicion = distancia;
    sumPosicion = (distanciaPosicion + 60);
    sumPosicion = parseInt(sumPosicion);
    aux = aux + arrText[i];
    var image = document.getElementById('screem');
    ctx.drawImage(image, sumPosicion, 67); 
     }
    }
```

[image]

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que en el canvas los coloque de derecha a izquierda, es decir como poner la imagen al contrario

Comment: Quité la etiqueta jquery, pues no se usa en el código incluido en la pregunta ni se menciona en el resto del cuerpo del mensaje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

itera a a la inversa:

```
if (check.checked & Bminus == '1') {
    for (var i = arrText.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
       parseFloat(arrText[i]);
       distancia = (arrText[i] + (aux)) / scala;
       distancia = parseInt(distancia);
       distanciaPosicion = distancia;
       sumPosicion = (distanciaPosicion + 60);
       sumPosicion = parseInt(sumPosicion);
       aux = aux + arrText[i];
       var image = document.getElementById('screem');
       ctx.drawImage(image, sumPosicion, 67); 
   }
}
```

```js
arrText = [435, 820, 795, 915];
  for (var i = arrText.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      console.log(arrText[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

invierte el orden de tu array

```js
arrText = [435, 820, 795, 915]

console.log(arrText);

arrText=arrText.reverse();

console.log(arrText);
```